# responsive.less and other responsive less files missing from Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am needing a responsive design at work and have a template project that uses
grunt to compile the final css file for bootstrap, but
the responsive grids is not working.

I checked out what .less files we are compiling and
we are compiling (among other things) responsive-utilities.less,

but people are saying to make sure to add the responsive.less file, and make
sure that gets compiled as well by Grunt.

Only problem is I can't find responsive.less anywhere that is supported by bootstrap.
I found people saying how to compile less into an end css file, and they had
responsive.less, but they did not say where they got it

for example: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/447/using-bootstrap-with-less/
That website even says to also include less files such as

responsive-1200px-min.less, responsive-768px-979px.less", responsive-767px-max.less, etc

But I can't find these anywhere.
Is there some secret repository that I don't know about where all of the less files 
are hiding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Those files are for Versions before 3.0

You can still get them for 2.3.2 [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html), but those extra files are not needed for 3.0+, as it is responsive out of the box, and [in fact requires certain things to be done to make it not responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive).

Comment: So it's built into bootstrap for 3.0, but for 3.0's less files, is the equivalent responsive-utility.less? Because that one is available with the other less files in 3.0.

Comment: I would not say that is the "equivalent," because in 3.0, the "equivalent" is spread out through various files to make the responsiveness. The `responsive-utilities.less` fixes a bug for IE, and includes classes that you can place on containing elements to make them visible/invisible at certain widths.