# Where are Bootstrap 3's .hidden- & .visible- for phone, tablet & desktop?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a specific requirement for my JQuery plugins to "know" what size Bootstrap is using (e.g. xs, sm, md, lg phone, tablet or desktop), so I decided to add classes to the body tag I could query.

Based on a couple of examples around the net I came up with this JQuery for Bootstrap I call jstrap:

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/52VtD/3767/

If you resize the output pane width, you will see the colours change based on the bootstrap size.

```
// Detect current bootstrap "size" and set appropriate "Size-" class on body element to allow for jQuery access (and additional styling)
function jstrap()
{
    var sizes = ["lg", "md", "sm", "xs", "phone", "tablet", "desktop"];
    var $el = $('<div>'),
        $body = $('body');
    $body.append($el);
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        var size = sizes[i];
        if ($el.addClass('hidden-' + size).is(':hidden'))
        {
            // Decorate body with a size class
            $body.addClass("Size-" + size);
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove this size (if previously present) as not applicable
            $body.removeClass("Size-" + size);
        }
    };
    $el.remove();
}
// Call jstrap on DOM load and on window resize
$(function ()
{
    $(window).resize(function ()
    {
        jstrap();
    });
    jstrap();
});
```

It sets `Size-` styles on the `body` element, based on the current bootstrap styling, but I found that the .hidden-phone, .hidden-tablet & .hidden-desktop do not appear to work. According to another post [responsive.less and other responsive less files missing from Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598656/responsive-less-and-other-responsive-less-files-missing-from-bootstrap) that functionality is included in bootstrap 3, but it appears to always have .hidden-desktop, .hidden-tablet and .hidden-phone set.

What am I missing?

*Note: this is formatted for .less, so no complaints about the code formatting :)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[In BS3 you just have `.hidden-xs/sm/md/lg`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities), phone/tablet/desktop apply for BS2.x only [as the question you linked states, by the way].

Comment: The linked question's answer implied the responsive functionality was built into BS3, but I see now that is not the case with the specific phone, tablet and desktop classes (which have been dropped).

Comment: .hidden-xs Targets Mobile phones